# What classes i am missing- Foundation 6?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

**I am learning foundation 6 framework and I am stuck in getting the desired result.**
[image]

> I want this three column grid approach up till mobile.

Below is what I am trying but unable to produce the result.

```css
.MyNewRow {
  background: red;
}

.MyNewRow .large-4 {
  background: yellow;
}

.MyNewRow .large-4+.large-4 {
  background: green;
}

.MyNewRow .large-4+.large-4+.large-4 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row MyNewRow">
  <div class=" large-4 ">I am Row 1</div>
  <div class=" large-4 ">I am Row 2</div>
  <div class=" large-4 ">I am Row 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want some output in desktop & mobile ? right?

Comment: yes like the image provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User class `small-#` for mobile:

```css
.MyNewRow {
  background: red;
}

.MyNewRow .small-4 {
  background: yellow;
}

.MyNewRow .small-4+.small-4 {
  background: green;
}

.MyNewRow .small-4+.small-4+.small-4 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row MyNewRow">
  <div class="small-4 columns">I am Row 1</div>
  <div class="small-4 columns">I am Row 2</div>
  <div class="small-4 columns">I am Row 3</div>
</div>
```

If you want same output on mobile & desktop then only used `small-#` class, no need to add  another class like `large-#` or `medium-#`

More info check this: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to add columns attribute in class

```
<div class="row MyNewRow">
  <div class=" large-4 columns">I am Row 1</div>
  <div class=" large-4 columns">I am Row 2</div>
  <div class=" large-4 columns">I am Row 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What abour large-4 small-4 ?? will it work without that til mobile?

Answer (score 1):

> I want this three column grid approach **up till mobile**.

Foundation framework is [Mobile First](http://foundation.zurb.com/mobile-first.html) you should use the logic:

> I want this three column grid approach **up till desktop (large)**.

Always follow this rule: first small, then medium, then large

```
<div class="row MyNewRow">
  <div class=" small-4 columns">I am Row 1</div>
  <div class=" small-4 columns">I am Row 2</div>
  <div class=" small-4 columns">I am Row 3</div>
</div>
```

If you don't define the small class, it's assumed as small-12